# "Tricky" bound with a constant independent of the function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the following "tricky" bound that I've found on a paper. Let me try to explain it without introducing all paper notations. Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ some unbounded continuous function satisfying $f(0)=0$. Assume that, for all $T\in(0,1)$ this function satisfies the following bound: $$
\qquad \qquad f(T)\leq c_1T(1+f(T))^{5/2} e^{c_2f(T)}, \quad \hbox{where}\quad c_1,c_2>0. \qquad \qquad (*)
$$
Now, the idea is to find $T^*\leq 1 $ small enough such that $f(t)\leq C$ for all $t\leq T^*$ for some constant $C>0$ independent of $f$. So, according to the authors, by defining the function $$
g(x):=\dfrac{x}{(1+\vert x\vert)^{5/2}e^{c_2x}},
$$
and choosing $T^*$ small enough such that $$
c_1T^*<\Vert g\Vert_{L^\infty},
$$
due to the continuity of $g(f(t)$, together with the fact that $g(f(0))=0$, we conclude that, for all $t\in(0,T^*)$ it holds: $$
f(t)\leq C,
$$
for some $C>0$. Now, it is still tricky to me to understand why this last constant $C$ does not depends on $f$. I feel like this constant seems "too" universal to be true. I feel like it should be possible to construct, for example, a sequence of functions $f_n$ taking "huge-values" closer and closer to zero, in other words, why it is not possible to construct a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_n$ satisfying something like $f_n(\tfrac{1}{n})=n$ that does not satisfy the previous inequality for that specific $C$ and $T^*$? I guess that the property I am asking for $f_n$ would contradict somehow inequality $(*)$. Does anyone has a rigorous explanation? It seems that it shouldn't be hard, but I got super confuse. Explicitly my question is, is this constant really independent of $f$?

Comment: Is $f$ positive?

Comment: @zhw. yes, it is

Comment: @zhw. My problem is that I feel like $C$ cannot be fully independent of $f$, for me it should appear at least an $L^\infty$  norm on a small ball around $t=0$ (because of the right-hand side of $(*)$). I am looking the argument in the following way: You could re-write inequality $(*)$ as $$\dfrac{f(T)}{(1+f(T))^{5/2}\exp(c_2f(T))}<c_1T,$$ which is basically $g(f(T))$.

Comment: @zhw.Then, by calling $C:=c_1T^*$, the inequality you obtain by choosing this specific $T^*$ is just (if i am looking it in the correct way): $$ \dfrac{f(T)}{(1+f(T))^{5/2}\exp(c_2f(T))} <C,$$ but this doesn't imply that $f(t)<\widetilde{C}$ for all $t$ (because you might pass now the divisor in the left-hand side to the right-hand side, no?)

Comment: Do $c_1,c_2$ depend on $f?$

Comment: @zhw. No, that's the point

Comment: You should specify $f\ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right to be doubtful about the alleged result. Suppose there is such a $T^*$ and constant $C.$ Define $f_n(T) = n|T|.$ Then for each $n=1,2,\dots $ there are constants $c_1,c_2,$ namely $c_1=n,c_2=1$ such that

$$f_n(T) = nT \le nT(1+n|t|)^{5/2}e^{n|t|}.$$

If $n>C/T^*,$ then

$$f_n(T^*) =nT^* >(C/T^*)T^*= C.$$

So there's no hope.